# Use UICollectionView and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionview

I'm using a project find on github that lets me use `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UICollectionView`, the project is [this](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController)

but when I save a new object like in this way:

```
NSManagedObject *doc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                    [doc setValue:[title contents] forKey:@"docName"];
[doc setValue:element valueforKey:@"Element"]

[self saveContext];
```

I receive this error:

```
 CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change  processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object. with userInfo (null)
```

I have tried to remove that project, and the save works, so I think the problem in that project, any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you export the NSManagedObject subclass and declare your object as that follows:

```
// At top of the file:
#import "Document.h"

// In your Method:
Document *doc = (Document *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
doc.docName = title.contents;

NSError *error = nil;
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Oh no! Something terrible happened! Error: %@", error);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Saved! Yay!");
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, i had already tried that method, i have open a new question with the full code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519172/use-uicollectionview-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller-doesnt-save