# Use UICollectionView and NSFetchedResultsController doesn't save

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionview

I'm using a project find on github that lets me use `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UICollectionView`, the project is [this](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController)

in my project i have a Core Data with two Entity, `Element` and `Document`, there is a relationship one to many between `Element` and `Document`, so an `Element` can have more `Document`, but a `Document` can have only one `Element`, then i do this in the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

ElementViewController *elementView = [[ElementViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ElementViewController" bundle:nil];
elementView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

DocumentViewController *documentView = [[DocumentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocumentViewController" bundle:nil];
documentView.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

elementView.documentView = documentView;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:elementView];

self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
 }
```

this is the App delegate, then in `ElementViewController` i have a `UICollectionView` with `NSFetchedResultsController`, and all works ok, when i select a `UICollectionViewCell` i open the `DocumentViewController`:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

self.documentView.element = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.documentView animated:YES];

}
```

then this is my `DocumentViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Element.h"

@interface DocumentViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) Element *element;

@end
```

And also here i have the `NSFetchedResultsController`, the filter in the predicate for the `Element` title:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
// Edit the entity name as appropriate.
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"docDate" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(element, $b, $b.name == %@).@count > 0", self.element.name]];

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

and then i have add also this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self reloadCollectionView];

[self addDocument];
}

- (void)reloadTableView
{
self.fetchedResultsController = nil; //Because not search every time for different Element
NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error in search %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
} else {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
}
```

then in the viewWillAppear there is the `addDocument` method:

```
- (void)addDocument
{
Document *document = (Document *)[NSEntityDescription
                                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[document setDocName:[title contents]];
[document setElement:self.element]; //here the app crash
}
```

and i receive these error:

```
    CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object. with userInfo (null)
2013-01-25 10:28:56.392 App[383:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't perform collection evaluate with non-collection object.'
```

anyone can help me?

EDIT:
This is the NSManagedObjectClass:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Document;

@interface Element : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * dateFormat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * dateFormat2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id img;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * imgDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imgUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * language;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pathDocuments;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * releaseDateWeek;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *documents;
@end

@interface Element (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addDocumentsObject:(Document *)value;
- (void)removeDocumentsObject:(Document *)value;
- (void)addDocuments:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeDocuments:(NSSet *)values;

@end

@interface ImageToDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer {
}
@end

Document.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Element;

@interface Document : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * docDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id docImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * docName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * docPath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * docSize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * docUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isDownloading;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isStored;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * pageNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * progressBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Element *element;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks to be that that in:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(element, $b, $b.name == %@).@count > 0", self.element.name]];
```

'element' does not resolve to a collection (as required by SUBQUERY), but merely a single object.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html